# Table 'users.users' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up a simple log in sign up system, but when I try to run this query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I get the error:

```
Table 'users.users' doesn't exist
```

Is there any way I could fix this? I know I am putting in the right table name.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is your DB Name?

Comment: The database name is userdatabase

Comment: try mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdatabase.users WHERE username='$user'")

Comment: so shouldnt it be `userdatabase.users`

Comment: As a sidenote, the other option is that in your mysql init functionality, you are opening the wrong database or DONT have one opened at all.  So it doesnt find the users table.

Comment: i dont know why you got Upvote for this?

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can any body help me [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008298/how-to-access-data-from-table-using-php-mysql)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can any body help me [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008298/how-to-access-data-from-table-using-php-mysql)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can any body help me [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008298/how-to-access-data-from-table-using-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userdatabase.users` WHERE username='$user'") or die(mysql_error());
```

From your example it seems that you have chosen different database than `userdatabase`, because the table is not found, so if you're dealing with tables from marked database, it's good way to change working database to `userdatabase` and then execute queries without namespace

See [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) (just mentioning mysql extension because you're using it) for database changing porpose, though get rid of [mysql extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I didnt downvote, but i find this gets around the idea of using the correct database to begin with.   You are accessing it from global, whereas i feel he should just adjust the scope of which database that session is looking at

Comment: @Fallenreaper It's good to choose database on which you're working, though this query should work just fine :)

Comment: i concur.  Though being stackoverflow, should i give you points for a working answer, or the best answer? *ponders*  Here, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Aber connecting to your database server, you need to select your database.

```
mysql_select_database('databasename');
```

Not sure if that is the correct functionname

Comment: this is the answer i would choose personally.  You are looking for `mysql_select_db('userdatabase');` though.   http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db